# Create user login JSP

Tags: jsp, text, authentication, storage

I am trying to create a quick fix solution to remedy hard-coded user names and passwords on a login page. I have been informed one of the simplest ways would be to store them in a text file.

Is it possible to read the value username and passwords from a text file and store them as variables and compare them to credentials entered by a user? I only need to acknowledge two different accounts, it's supposed to simulate different levels of privileges.

if userone do this..

if usertwo do this..

```
public boolean isAuthenticated(String username, String password)   throws    FileNotFoundException{
    boolean status = true;
    File file = new File("");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

    List<Login> login = new ArrayList<Login>();

    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        String [] details = line.split(":");
        String storedUsername = details[0];
        String storedPassword = details[1];
        Login l = new Login(username, password);

        if(storedUsername.equals(username)&& storedPassword.equals(password)){
            status = true;
        }else{
            status = false;
        }

    }
    return status;
}
```

Thanks!! Chance212...

Edit: So I have got it working, the only issue I have is reading from the text file and continually comparing to the parameters passed in. It's simply acknowledging the last value, only allowing generic user to be logged in and not the admin

Question: How do would I continually read the text file and compare the values being passed to it?

Thanks! Chance212

Comment: At the Starting, It Looks like you want a solution for username & password using file handling.. But I can't get those last lines **if userone......**

Comment: Sorry my fault. user one and user two will have different privileges available to them, depending on which users credentials are entered will determine what jsp file loads. I shall looking into file handling though thanks!

Comment: To make it clearer it'd be similar to  having accounts for an admin and general user. Hope that clears it up a bit

Comment: Assuming that you only need to differentiate between the users (including Admin) at the login page.. Let a file named **UserPass.txt** be there containing username and password (each user and thier pass in a new line).. In the Servlet/ JSP (where you want to Differentiate), check **if(formsUsername.equals("admin") && formsPassword.equals(adminPass)){ load Admin Page}** else{ReadData from file UserPass.txt like **while(Strings not null){uname=firstString, upass=secondString; and compare with form input}**

Comment: I may be mistaken but that would still be hardcoded wouldn't it, if the admin username and password are contained within the jsp? However I could create a method within a java class that contains that operation couldn't I? simple call the method in the JSp and pass the username and password that have been entered?

Comment: Ok.. I need to know whether you want a file for user & pass,  **or** a class that authenticates users, **or** both..

Comment: Ideally both please, should we move this to a chat to follow Stack rules?

Comment: A Class Authenticator with parameterized constructor (String uname, String upass) and a function isAuthorized() returning boolean and a boolean variable auth which will be everywhere in this class.. In the Constructor, starting reading the username & password from file and compare constantly with the parameters, if any username and password matches set auth=true and break that loop.. **Note: isAuthorized() will return auth, first username & password in file will be of admin, so before the while loop check that its admin or not, also add a function isAdmin()**

Comment: Usage in JSP.. **Authenticator aa = new Authenticator(formUsername, formPassword); if(aa.isAuthorized()){** if(aa.isAdmin()){ redirect to admin page} else { redirect to user page}       **} else{**   user not exist     **}**

Comment: Its not checking the last.. Its working fine.. Just 1 thing, when status=true then break the loop.. Else it will check for other user:pass in the file also..

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!!